# Rails, Can't deploy app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, pg

I am new to rails, but got an app working great. Now I want to publish it to the web for a test. I am trying heroku, but can't get it to work.

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'carrierwave'
gem "rmagick"

gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'
gem 'prawn'
gem 'prawn-table'
gem 'bcrypt'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
#gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

And the error when doing the git push:
[image]

The thing is when doing the git push, it cannot install pg, tilt (it is not even in my gemfile, why does it even try?), and prawn, but mainly fails on pg. 
I am doing this on a windows machine. 
I got successfully to this part of the heroku guide for windows: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-jruby#deploy-the-app

Then tried deleting the rails files and folders, and copying over the ones from my app, but it fails as shown above.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Looks like you might need the rubyracer

Comment: Did you try to install gem pg locally? Heroku use gemfile.lock to install gems and their dependencies. Looks like you have gem pg in Production mode only, that means it will not be installed when you do just bundle install. Hence not part of gemfile.lock and causes failure in deployment.

Comment: @madyrockss Absolutely agree.  Use PostgreSQL locally not SQLite and you can be better assured it will push.  I have this same configuration based on Windows and including both staging and production on Heroku and it works great.  Note on tilt, one of the gems you installed likely requires tilt so bundle will grab it for you to satisfy that prereq.  Actually, use "gem install pg" to install pg locally for test and you can resolve any issues outside of bundle.

Comment: @aulait A few hints on starting with Rails especially on Windows and working with Heroku.  BitNami Rubystack is a great installer.  Rails Composer is wonderful to build the scaffold.  railstutorial.org is the best tutorial out there.  You can't do RVM with Windows and there isn't a great alternative so, if you are going to get into it, consider OS X or Linux, though I've gone production with Windows and will get to Linux.  Be cautious about getting into JRuby unless you must have Java.  You don't need RubyRacer to do native JavaScript, only to embed it which is 100% different. Rubymine for IDE

Comment: Looks like it's complaining about JRuby and RMagick, as [JRuby does not support C extensions]( https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/C-Extension-Alternatives). Consider using `mini_magick` instead.